Need help in JupyterLab Python - Reading Excel and Passing variables
I'm looking to read excel file (referrals.xls) in batch mode.  Goal is to read each row and send a text message welcoming them, and passing their name and the facility where the can live.
Using data frame to load the data.  I've limited my test to 2 rows for testing.
The code runs and I receive 2 messages.  That's the good part.
The problem is that it's not passing the correct data.  In the first text, it didn't pass the facility, but rather the literal {facility}.  It also cut some of the text from the message (not passed variable).  it does pass the url link to the welcome video correctly.
For the 2nd message, it passes name, and facility correctly, but the URL of the video is truncated.
The expectation is to pass a welcome text.  Dear "New guest", Exciting news!
...
Value of staying here message.
then
"Click the link below to watch a short video explaining the benefits.
Code below: 
import pandas as pd
from twilio.rest import Client
account_sid = 'My Twilio SID'
auth_token = 'My Twilio Auth_token'

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

df = pd.read_excel('/users/micha/referral.xlsx', sheet_name='referraltracker', header=4, usecols=['Phone', 'Name', 'Review Status', 'Approval Date','Facility'])

df.head()

# below is output from df.head()
# Name  Facility    Phone   Review Status   Approval Date
# 0 Smith, Suzie    OH-CLE: Park Terrace    18473233003 Approved    2024-05-15
# 1 Judy, Judy  TX-SUG: Brookdale Lakeway   18473233003 Approved    2024-05-15

df.types

# below is output from df.head()
# Name                     object
# Facility                 object
# Phone                     int64
# Review Status            object
# Approval Date    datetime64[ns]
# dtype: object

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    name = row['Name']
    facility = row['Facility']
    phone_number = row['Phone']
    message_body = (
        f"Dear {name}, Exciting News!\n\n"
        "We'd like to welcome you to our new {facility}\n"
        "\nThis remarkable opportunity."
        "\n\nWhy is this great for you?\n"
        "*\tConvenience: Say goodbye to inconvenient.  and a more text here\n"
        "Click the link below to watch a short video explaining the benefits\n"
        "\nWe're committed to your well-being and comfort!")
    message=client.messages.create(
        body=message_body,
        from_='+TWILIO_Purchased_Phone_#',
        to=phone_number)

